# component not handling empty prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

I have a component **data.table.vue** and other components for eg **abc.vue** and **xyz.vue**.

inside this data.table.vue, a paragraph to render depending on the prop received by the it.. However, not both my components **abc.vue** and **xyz.vue** will send props.. only **abc.vue** needs to send props..  for eg:

in abc.vue:

```
<template>
   <data-table 
     :isShown=true
   <data-table>
</template>
```

and in xyz.vue no props

```
<template>
   <data-table 
   </data-table>
</template>
```

and in data.table.vue

```
 <p v-if="isShown"> hello world </p>
```

but I want this paragraph to be always shown for **xyz** component.. 
and only for **abc.vue**, i want this paragraph to render according to the props isShown.. However, even in **xyz.vue** , its being rendered depending on the props sent in **abc.vue**..

Please help ..

Comment: Try using a computed prop inside `data.table.vue` that returns `true` if there is no `isShown`, or the value of `isShown`

Comment: Put your `v-if` on your xyz component or add `:isShown="isShown"` in <data-table>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a default prop like this.

```
   export default {
     props: {
        isShown: {
        type: Object,
        default: true
       }
    }
}
```

Default will be taken when no props are passed.

Answer (score 0):

For **Vue3** with the composite API you can set default props like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    isShown: {
      type: boolean,
      default: true
    },
  },
  setup() {},
})
</script>
```

And with the script setup

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    isShown: boolean
  }>(),
  {
    isShown: true
  }
)
</script>
```